# How to make code run every 30 minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I have this code in home controller

```
  def index
    urls = RssStream.select("rss_streams.url").all.map { |v| v[:url] }
    RssStream.update_all_feeds(urls)
  end
```

And I want to make run this code every 30.minutes.
How can I do it?

I've tried through gem 'whenever', nothing happens

Comment: What code did you try with `whenever`?

Comment: You could use the `whenever` or `clockwork` gems for example to call your method every 30 minutes.

Comment: @Dogbert `every 1.hours do
  runner "urls = RssStream.select("rss_streams.url").all.map { |v| v[:url] }
    RssStream.update_all_feeds(urls)"
end
`

Comment: what if your code runs longer than 30 minutes? Do you permit all subsequent runs to stack up without limit?

Comment: @Anton, and what didn't work?

Comment: @Dogbert  /Users/ipatov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/whenever-0.8.2/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `instance_eval': config/schedule.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
...= RssStream.select("rss_streams.url").all.map { |v| v[:url] ...

Comment: @Anton, You have `"` inside `"`, you need to escape them. PS: you should have posted all this info in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should not be placed in your controller. Extract it into an [own Rake task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) and let that one be [executed by whenever](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised)!

Answer (score 1):

Write a script for the code and schedule a cron job of 30 mins. You can use webmin for this.
Link for ref:- 
http://www.hosting.com/support/webmin/create-new-cron-jobs-using-the-webmin-interface
or
http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You should put it into Rake task and probably use cron job to execute it.